# Opening mail.box file in Domino Server

Tags: c#, .net, lotus-domino

I want to programmatically access Mail.box file in Domino Server.
Using C#.

Before opening it i was to see it's contents.
My question is that how can we open file with .box extension?
Especially Mail.box file in Domino Server.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand you fully. Are you saying that code like this doesn't work when attempting to access the mailbox on the server?

```
Domino.NotesDatabase database = session.GetDatabase("", "mail.box", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mail.box is in fact a notes database. So opening it like a normal database is possible. However this is managed exclusively by the server. Email messages appear in this database only momentarily. Literally for a second. The only messages you will be able to monitor are emails the SMTP process cannot send.

If this is your intention, I would suggest consulting a Notes Admin as I think you can configure the server to alert you in the case of "dead" emails.